# How do I add the Bootstrap Country picker plugin to select a country with flag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, query-builder

I created a query builder where users can select a country. It's working fine:

[image]

I want to use the Bootstrap Country picker with flags instead of typing all the countries' names in a list.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>

<div id="builder"></div>
<script>
  $('#builder').queryBuilder({
    plugins: [
      'bt-tooltip-errors',
      'not-group'
    ],

    filters: [{
      id: 'country',
      label: 'country',
      type: 'string',
      input: 'select',
      values: {
        Austria: 'Austria',
        Germany: 'Germany',
        UK: 'UK',
        France: 'France',
        Italy: 'Italy',
        Brasil: 'Brasil',
        India: 'India'
      }

    }]
  });
</script>

<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-flags="true">
</div>
```

I was trying to insert `<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-flags="true"></div>` somehow instead of

```
values: {
  Austria: 'Austria',
  Germany: 'Germany',
  UK: 'UK',
  France : 'France',
  Italy : 'Italy',
  Brasil : 'Brasil',
  India : 'India' }
```

But without success. How do I insert this country picker in my query builder?

Comment: You really cant do anything (sane, cross browser) as long as you are using <select>'s. You must replace the select with some fancy replacement that is based on <li>'s, <span>'s or similar.